# Drawing a from two series of data in d3

Tags: d3.js

Should be a pretty simple task actually..... I'm following this [tutorial](http://www.janwillemtulp.com/2011/03/23/tutorial-line-interpolations-in-d3/) but I cant seem to make the line appear. The only difference is that i'm working with two sets of data and he is working with only one (Y values are scales by index position).

I transformed my data in the folowing manner

```
var series_data = {'x':x,'y':y};
g.append("svg:path").attr("d", line(series_data));
```

please take a look in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JfDDm/) and tell me what am I doing wrong before i lose it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things. First, don't encode your numbers as strings (the values for "y"), this will mess up things later. Second, there's some confusion with the data structures. The data you generate for `series_data` looks like

```
{'x': [...], 'y': [...]}
```

while your line function seems to be expecting something like

```
[{'x': [...], 'y': [...]}, {'x': [...], 'y': [...]}, ...]
```

I've fixed this in [the updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JfDDm/2/) and also added CSS for the created path so you can see it.

Comment: Thanks man. It did the trick. Do you know if there is a way of making the line between the dots straight ? (and not curved ? if you change one of the y values you'll see it).

Comment: Just remove `.interpolate("basis")` from the definition of `line`.